# How to check-in a detached head git project into a new remote repp?

Tags: git

I cloned an opensource project at a specific tag v036.  Now I want to make sure that I'm saving my changes into my local git repo while I mess around. I tried just changing the remote url and doing a push but it tells me:

```
HEAD detached at v0.36
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   integration

no changes added to commit
```

Is there a proper way to do this or am I asking too much of git? Most of the answers I can find are about how to check your code back into the original repo but I just want to make a copy with my changes on my git server.

Thank you.

Comment: Try checking out a branch first? `git checkout -b branch-name` or `git switch -c branch-name`

Answer (score 1):

You could stage and commit your changes, then create a new feature branch from that commit and push:

```
# from detached HEAD state
git add integration
git commit -m 'your message here'
git checkout -b feature
git push origin feature
```

Comment: I think the branch needs creating before committing?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Not true, and committing while in the detached HEAD state is perfectly fine.  But if we want to keep the work in a long term usable state, we need to create an actual branch at some point.

Comment: This put the files up on the repos but complained:  * [new branch]          feature -> feature
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature': cannot lock ref
'refs/remotes/origin/feature': 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/bownn' exists; canno
t create 'refs/remotes/origin/feature'

Comment: @evolutionxbox (and Tim): note that `git checkout -b <branch>; git commit` and `git commit; git checkout -b <branch>` produce the same end result (assuming no errors) since `git commit` updates the current branch if there is one, or updates `HEAD` in detached-HEAD mode.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: that just means you can't use the *name* `feature`. Use `feature/something`, or a name other than `feature`. The name `feature/bownn` exists on the remote and therefore the remote refuses to use `feature` as a branch name, treating `feature/` as if it were a folder full of branch names instead. (Git applies this limitation so that it can literally store names as file-paths on host OSes, where the directory-vs-file conflict is a real thing.)